# SpringBoot MVC, Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Stack: SpringBoot, Spring MVC and Thymeleaf
I followed https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/
I would like now to do a loop for which each iteration updates the ${name} in the view. (without calling multiple time the controller).

I would say I want to make the page/view dynamic? But I miss the vocabulary of it and therefor I can't find a proper way to do it.

Anyone knows how ?

See you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Send the list from your controller to the requested html page and then use `th:each` on your html page to populate the values.

Comment: Thanks Sumit, totally makes sens now I didn’t think it that way.